# He who accuses the whole world convicts only himself

Tags: quotes

Or something like that.  Does anybody know the exact text and source of this quotation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The oldest form I can find seems to come from Edmund Burke, 1855, in his *Letter to Sheriffs*, collected eg [here](http://www.ourcivilisation.com/smartboard/shop/burkee/maxims/chap9.htm):

> But he that accuses all mankind of corruption ought to remember that he is sure to convict only one.

If this is indeed the original, then it has gained in pithiness with repetition; the wordings that seem commonest now are along the lines of

> He that accuses all, convicts only one.